# Yosemite update deleted user files - but no old user folder in the system

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, auto-update

I am wondering, after the OS was updated, a user created the same user account with same name and same full name. So there is no old folder with same name. However, the ID number is 501. Is there still any chance of getting the old files? Disk space taken is only 13 GB.

It is related to [How do i get back my old user account after upgrading to OS X Yosemite 10.10.2?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175368/how-do-i-get-back-my-old-user-account-after-upgrading-to-os-x-yosemite-10-10-2)

Answer (score -1):

I didn't think it was possible to create the same named account if there is already one there. Upgrades don't remove user accounts or data. Are you sure you didn't reimage it instead? 10.10.2 isn't even available anymore - if you upgrade Yosemite you'd get 10.10.5 from Apple.

Comment: 10.10.2 Combo Update is still [available](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1786)